# Is it possible Nginx do http redirect based on memcache key/value result?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, memcached, static-content

I want a web server based on nginx, which receives a HTTP request (http://example.com) and check on memcached server "example.com" key.

If this key value is equal to firstsite.com send http code 302 (redirect) to firstsite.com. Otherwise if value is equal to foo.com then redirect sent to client goes to foo.com.

Is it possible ? I don't want do it via Lua or some other language.

Comment: Is not possible without additional module. I do it using Lua with a good nginx performance.